# minimum number of operations to get a target number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, dynamic-programming, backtracking

If there is a list of digits in string format, e.g. ["1", "5", "8"], list of valid operations are "+","-", and "*" and a target number. Find the minimum number of operands are needed to build the target number. ALSO, you can concatenate the digits in the given list. target number range is [0,99999]

Example:

```
 ex1:
   digits: ["1"]
   Target: 1
   min number of operations needed is 0 since 1 can be represented with 1

 ex2:
   digits: ["1"]
   Target: 11
   min number of operations needed is 0 since 11 can be represented with 1 (concatenate 1s)

 ex3:
   digits: ["1"]
   Target: 21
   min number of operations needed is 2 since:
      11 + 11 - 1 = 21 ==> two operations
```

Any algorithmic solution? I don't think greedy algorithms will work as we have to explore the entire space of possibilities, which leads to backtracking/recursion/DP. Having "-" makes it a bit non-intuitive to me as we can exceed the target and come back to it using "-" as opposed to if it was just "+" and "*".

Comment: question: can you concatenate later? i.e. can you make 21 by doing concatenate(1+1, 1)

Comment: @Mark: that would be a quite unusual operation in such a quiz.

Comment: this is reminiscient of the numbers round of Countdown/Letters and Numbers/Des chiffres et des lettres([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_chiffres_et_des_lettres#Numbers_round)) but with a requirement to get exactly onto the number, and in the minimum number of rounds. The main difference (other than the ones I just mentioned) is the concatenation, which explodes the possible options at each edge of the graph

Comment: @Mark: back in the nineties or so, they introduced a computer to play the game simultaneously.

Comment: @Alan I'd also say, concatentation ought to be an operation - you *are* changing the numbers, so it doesn't make sense to not call it an operation

Comment: @mark, the answer is no. You only can concatenate the given digits

Comment: @Mark that's what the question as for and only minimum number of mathematical operations should be counted

Comment: another question: can you continue concatentating indefinitely? i.e. could you do 1111111111? or are only two digits allowed to be concatenated at once

Comment: at many times as you want. for example you can create 99999 with out needing any operands just having digit "9"

Comment: even though you have only included "1" as the only digit in the example, it may as well be ["1", "11", "111", "1111" etc.]. This essentially dooms your hope of getting any answer for anything where the number of steps is larger than 2 or 3

Comment: What are the rules for the evaluation of the expressions ? E.g. what is 1+2*3 ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust 1+2*3 is obviously 7

Comment: Only obvious for you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust in math and computer machines 1+2*3 is always 7. That's a rule.

Comment: @Alan: left-to-right evaluation is also a rule.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that also is part of the same set of rules :). see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations. Actually the first example is exactly 1+2*3 :)))